# Will_paginate inside form with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, save, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate pagination for my survey questions.

Each question has_one answer.

Each page contain 5 questions. While going to next page i lost the previous page answers. How can i save that records before_paginate.

```
<%= form_for(@attempt, :url => attempt_scope(@attempt)) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
     <div id="accordion" class="questions">
       <% @questions.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
         <h3 data-id="<%= question.id %>" >Question </h3>
         <div>
          <p> <div><%= question.text %>  </div>     
        <%= hidden_field_tag "survey_attempt[answers_attributes][#{index}][question_id]", question.id %>

          </p>
         <div class="input select rating-c">
           <label for="example-c">Rating values displayed on the bars:</label>
              <%#=select_tag "survey_attempt[answers_attributes][#{index}][option_id][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@options, "id", "text"),{ class: " #{question.id}list select  mybutton",id: "example-c",include_blank: true, name: "optionname"} %>
                <%=select_tag "survey_attempt[answers_attributes][#{index}][option_id][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@options, "id", "text"),{id:"example-c"} %>
         </div>
        </div>         
       <% end %>
     </div>
     <%= will_paginate @questions, :class=>"mybutton page pagination", renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, params: request.params %>
  <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [will\_paginate with request params in rails3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755799/will-paginate-with-request-params-in-rails3)

Comment: i didn't get any proper answer there

Comment: read this [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use ajax to submit answers when a user checks or select an option. You can get more information on ajax [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

**Edit**

There are two ways by which you can do ajax, either you can go for remote: true in your form which is explained in the earlier link i posted or you can call an ajax request by jquery. I think jquery one will be cleaner in your case.

Let's suppose you have checkboxes for your answers to a question. You will have something like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="answers">  #but each question will have different answers so you need something to differentiate so you will need some data attribute.
<input type="checkbox" class="answers" data-question="question_id">
```

Now you can target each answer by one jquery function, something like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".answers",function(){
 var question = $(this).data("question"); #gets the id of question
 $.ajax({
   url: url_for_your_custom_action, #need to make a method in controller and create answer for that question by the id of question you get from content in params
   type: "POST", #a post request because you sending question id.
   data: { content: question } #this will send your question id. you can get it by params[:content]
 });
});
```

This way whichever checkbox a user ticks it will call the same method and you won't have to repeat your code.

Comment: Yep, this is what i would do.  You will need to wrap each checkbox in a `remote_form_for`

Comment: can't i override Will_paginate controller to achieve my requirement. I may escape from error conditions in ajax

Comment: @santosh why would you want to change a library for such small thing? It will be much better if you use ajax. You simply need to make your custom method in controller and then call that method each time user ticks his/her answer

Comment: can u post some example that how can i save through ajax

Comment: Nicely explained!